# WordCount Versions different execution time

Tags: hadoop

I may have a fairly small cluster and to test it a bit I used the two wordcount version from https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable1/mapred_tutorial.html and used to hadoop.*.examples from hadoop itself.

Now to the "Problem" the two Versions of wordcount have two complete different execution times. The Version 1 is factor 5 faster than Version 2. I also modified the code a bit to make it more similar and it shows still this incredible difference.

Could anybody explain this behavior or is it something is did wrong? And if so what?

Answer (score 0):

Version 2 just does more things, namely it uses DistributedCache to skip words that match patterns.

Comment: indeed ... but i threw it out to make them both more alike... the two do exactly the same thing but the supposedly older version runs so much faster.